# Solving second order nonhomogeneous ODE where the RHS is a random process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, random-functions

**Context:** I'm trying to characterize the [metastability behavior of a digital latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Metastability).

I'm modeling two cross-coupled inverters as [RC circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) with negative gain. One of the inverters has a source of noise at its input (denoted $v_n(t)$) which is a gaussian white noise process.

This gives me a system of two ODE's:

$$
V_I(t) + \tau \frac{dV_I(t)}{dt}=-AV_O(t)
$$
$$
V_O(t) + \tau \frac{dV_O(t)}{dt}=-A\left(V_I(t)+v_n(t)\right)
$$

Substituting and re-arranging for $V_O$ yields

$$
V_O''+\frac{2}{\tau}V_O'+\frac{1-A^2}{\tau^2}V_O=\frac{-A}{\tau^2}\left(v_n+v_n'\right)
$$

In the absences of this noise source, the second order homogeneous equation has a simple complementary answer
$$
y_c=C_1e^{-t/\tau_1}+C_2e^{t/\tau_2} 
$$
where
$$
\tau_1 = \frac{\tau}{A+1}, \tau_2 = \frac{\tau}{A-1}
$$
For simplicity assume $A \gg 1$ so $\tau_1=\tau_2=\tau'=\frac{\tau}{A}$

In general, I'm concerned with initial conditions of the form $V_O(0)=-Av_s,V_O'(0)=0$ (i.e. some sampled, constant voltage at $V_I$ gained up to $V_O$).

This gives a solution (again approximating) of 
$$
V_O(t)=-A\frac{v_s}{2}\left(e^{\frac{t}{\tau'}}+e^{\frac{-t}{\tau'}}\right)
$$

And finally, the quantity I'm trying to characterize is the time delay to some fixed voltage, that is $t_D$ such that $V_O(t_D)=-V_F$. $t_D$ will vary with $v_s$:
$$
t_D=\tau'ln\left(\frac{2V_F}{Av_s}\right)
$$

If you've stuck with me so far... Thank you!

**The Problem:**

How do I solve for the particular solution of:
$$
V_O''+\frac{2}{\tau}V_O'+\frac{1-A^2}{\tau^2}V_O=\frac{-A}{\tau^2}\left(v_n+v_n'\right)
$$
where $v_n(t)$ is a gaussian random process?

I know that derivatives of gaussian processes are also gaussian, so I can make the RHS into a single gaussian, but I need to know its parameters. Even after that, I need to solve for $V_o$, then apply solve the inverse to get a distribution of $t_D$ for a given $v_s$, which is ultimately what I'm looking for.

This is way beyond anything I learned about differential equations. Explicit solutions are greatly appreciated, as are references to the appropriate techniques!

Answer (score 1):

With the equation of form:

$$ x'' + 2 \beta x' +  \alpha x + \gamma  = f(t) $$

You can find the solution using a convolution. To do this you find solutions to:

$$ x'' + 2 \beta x' +  \alpha x + \gamma  = \delta(t - t_0) $$

Where $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution and the final solution becomes:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_\tau (t) f(\tau) d\tau $$

Where $x_\tau$ is the solution for delta distribution located at $\tau$. In your case this would be something like: $ x_\tau(t) = \mathbb{I}(t>\tau)[\exp(- \beta (t-\tau)\exp(i \sqrt{\alpha}(t-\tau))] $. Given that this would be a linear operator acting on gaussian process you should get something gaussian again.